# Is there a way to detect and reload when css file changes while executing the TypeScript tsc-watch command?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, monorepo, lerna

I'm configuring monorepo using **React, lerna, yarn workspace, storybook**

The module directory was configured using storybook + typescript + React in common under packages directory

When developing storybook components with tsc-watch commands in the development environment, the compilation is reloaded when the tsx and ts files are changed, but it does not detect and reload the css files.

Is there a way to automatically reload the tsc command when changing the css file?

Here are the scripts of my tsconfig.json and package.json :)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

---

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib/",
    "copy-files": "copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.html src/**/*.css lib",
    "build": "yarn clean && tsc && yarn copy-files",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"yarn copy-files\"",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
```

Comment: I do not know but I suggest you to check nodemon, it works as a charm.